# std::sort не работает для std::list

Tags: c++, visual-c++, сортировка, stl

```
#include <list>
#include <iostream> 
#include <algorithm>
#include <iterator>

using namespace std;

int main() {
    list<int> l;

    l.push_back(0);
    l.push_back(0);
    l.push_back(0);
    l.push_back(0);

    list<int>::iterator i;

    for (i = l.begin(); i != l.end(); i++)
        cout << *i << endl;

    cout << endl;

    i = l.begin();

    i++;
    i++;

    l.insert(i, 999);

    for (i = l.begin(); i != l.end(); i++)
        cout << *i << endl;

    cout << endl;

    i = l.end();
    --i;
    --i;

    l.insert(i, 200);

    for (i = l.begin(); i != l.end(); i++)
        cout << *i << endl;

    sort(l.begin(), l.end()); // ругается на код заголовка

    return 0;
}
```

error C2784: '_RanIt1::difference_type std::operator -(std::move_iterator<_RanIt> &,const std::move_iterator<_RanIt2> &)' : could not deduce template argument for 'std::move_iterator<_RanIt> &' from 'std::_List_iterator<_Mylist>'

Answer (score 1, accepted):

все понял сам разобрался sort() для list работать не будет

Comment: Ну, почему же? Вот, пишут [есть sort для list](http://www.cplusplus.com/reference/list/list/sort/)

Answer (score 4):

`std::sort` требует итераторы с произвольным доступом (Random Access Iterator), а итераторы `std::list` - это двунаправленные итераторы (Bidirectional Iterator).

Об этом и говорит ошибка компилятора - у итераторов `std::list` нету `operator-` (вычитания).